# Positive Segments

Tags: time-limit-exceeded, vectors, c++20

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> You have an array A of size n, containing −1 or 1 only, and s segments (not necessarily different). Each segment is defined by 2 integers li and ri (1 ≤ li ≤ ri ≤ n) and represent the subarray A<sub>li</sub>, A<sub>li +1</sub> , ..., A<sub>ri</sub> of the array A.

> A segment [li, ri] is called positive if the sum of elements in the subarray is strictly greater than 0. That is A<sub>li</sub>, A<sub>li +1</sub> , ..., A<sub>ri</sub> ≥0. Forexample,ifA=[−1,−1,1,−1,1],thenthesegments[3,5]and[5,5] are positive (sum of elements is greater than 0), but the segments [1, 2] or [1, 5] are not positive.

> Now you have q queries. In each query, you are given an integer j (1 ≤ j ≤ n) such that you set A<sub>j</sub> = |A<sub>j</sub>| (Absolute value of A<sub>j</sub>). You have to find the minimum number of queries after which at least k (≤ s) of given segments become positive or tell it is impossible.

> Note: It might happen that there already exists k positive segments.

> Input
> First line of input consists of number of test cases t. Every test case is defined as follows-
> – First line contains 2 integer n and s.
> – Next line contains n integers where ith integer denotes Ai.
> – Following s lines contain 2 integers li and ri defining ith segment.
> – Next line contains 2 integers q and k.
> – Next line contains q integers where ith integer denotes x corresponding to ith query.

> Output
> For each test case, output a line containing the minimum number of queries needed for that case. If it is impossible in all the queries then output -1 in that case.

There is an additional criteria to just use three libraries, i.e., iostream, vector & cstdlib.

My code for the same is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int countPositiveSegments(vector<int>& A, vector<vector<int>>& sets) {
    int count = 0;
    for (const vector<int>& segment : sets) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = segment[0] - 1; i < segment[1]; i++) {
            sum += A[i];
        }
        if (sum > 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    int total_cases;
    cin >> total_cases;
    while (total_cases > 0) {
        int n, s, q, k;
        cin >> n >> s;
        vector<int> A;
        vector<vector<int>> sets;
        while (n > 0) {
            int temp;
            cin >> temp;
            A.push_back(temp);
            n--;
        }
        while (s > 0) {
            int temp1, temp2;
            vector<int> temp3;
            cin >> temp1 >> temp2;
            temp3.push_back(temp1);
            temp3.push_back(temp2);
            sets.push_back(temp3);
            s--;
        }
        cin >> q >> k;
        vector<int> queries;
        while (q > 0) {
            int temp;
            cin >> temp;
            queries.push_back(temp);
            q--;
        }

        // Initialize variables
        int queries_needed = -1;
        int total_positive_sets = countPositiveSegments(A, sets);

        if (total_positive_sets < k) {
            // If there are not enough positive sets, then iterate through queries
            for (int i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++) {
                int x = queries[i] - 1; // Adjust the 0-based index
                A[x] = abs(A[x]);
                int new_positive_sets = countPositiveSegments(A, sets);

                if (new_positive_sets >= k) {
                    queries_needed = i + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (queries_needed != -1) {
            cout << queries_needed << endl;
        } else {
            cout << -1 << endl;
        }

        total_cases--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works perfectly fine for:

```
Input (stdin)
2
5 2
-1 -1 1 -1 -1
1 2
2 5
6 1
3 1 1 2 5 3
5 3
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1
1 3
2 2
1 1
3 2
2 4 5

Your Output (stdout)
4
-1

Expected Output
4
-1
```

For a few of the hidden test cases, it provides a Time Limit Exceeded error. I'm trying to ascertain a new way which can solve the problem.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

**Algorithmic deficiencies**.

- `countPositiveSegments` has a time complexity proportional to the combined size of all segments, which can grow quadratically with the size of array. And you do it for every query. I am not surprised at all that the solution times out.

  You can count initial positive segments much faster by computing a accumulated sum of the array, `acc[i] = acc[i-1] + A[i]`) (in \$O(n)\$ time); then the segment is positive if `acc[ri] > acc[li]` (in \$O(s)\$ time).
- You don't need to recount positive segments when `A[x]` is `1`. Fix is trivial.
- Once a segment becomes positive, you don't need to account for it anymore. Just forget that it existed.
- If `A[x]` is `-1`, only the segments containing `x` are affected; you don't need to bother about the rest. The fix is less trivial: you need more elaborate data structure. A segment tree perhaps?

**Code review**.

- `using namespace std;` is a very bad habit.
- `temp, temp1, temp2, temp3` are not the greatest names. If you don't know how to name a variable, think twice: do you really need it?
- More functions, please. Every loop implements an important operation, and therefore deserves a name, like `get_array`, `get_segments`, etc.
- I don't see the need for `vector<int> queries`. It is a waste of space. You should process queries one by one.
- `if (total_positive_sets < k)` does not need to be special cased. In fact, doing so results in the bug: if this condition is initially false, the loop is not entered, and `queries_needed` remains `-1`, even though you already have enough positive segments. A natural way to write the loop is

  ```
    while ((total_positive_sets < k) && (queries < q))
  ```
- `vector<int> temp3` does not deserve to be a `vector`. It is a `pair<int, int>`.

Comment: If you read the question again, it is mentioned only three libraries are allowed so pair can't be implemented

Comment: Instead of `std::pair<int, int>` just create a `struct segment { int li; int ri; }`. Then `std::vector<segment> sets; … sets.emplace_back(temp1, temp2);`